# check boxes not visible in ie 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp-classic, internet-explorer-11

I have an application where in I build the html data at the middle tier level and pass this html onto the browser. Within a javascript function I replace the .innerHTML of a particular div element with the html data obtained from middle tier.

The html data consists of checkboxes and these are displayed fine in ie 7 and ie 8, but these boxes disappear when I hover/click on them only in case of ie 11

What could be the reason?

Comment: please add the relevant code that would allow this problem to be reproduced

Comment: Hi Quince, I have edited the problem with an abstract code, let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Unfortunately i can not reproduce a problem with abstract code. You would just need to show what ends up in the browser as this is where the problem can first be identified even if the root is some where else.